# JRuby segfault on Suse

Tags: jruby, suse, torquebox

I am experiencing is the following segfault when I run jruby on suse.

[22478.479263] java[1729]: segfault at 7ff4b1604320 ip 00007ff4b1604320 sp 00007ff4d5c80e98 error 14 in libgcc_s.so.1[7ff4b1a37000+16000]

This is running java-1_6_0-ibm & jruby 1.6.7

I have uninstalled/reinstalled java and tinkered with the memory settings with no luck. Any help/pointers would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The segfaults are most likely due to JRuby's JNI library stub for doing native calls being incompatible with IBM's Java.

You should run with `-Xnative.enabled=false` on the command line or set `JRUBY_OPTS=-Xnative.enabled=false`.